# Get radio button value from database

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to pull my radio button value from a database and be able to edit it. How do I go about doing this? Everything inserts fine, but when I try and search I get an error of "Notice: Undefined index: isVolunteer in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_insert_update_delete_search.php on line 38"

**My Code:**

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $password ="";
 $database = "2104299_test";

 $personID = "";
 $personFName = "";
 $personLName = "";
 $personAddress = "";
 $personContact = "";
 $personEmail = "";
 $personPassword = "";
 $isVolunteer = "";


 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

 // connect to mysql database
try{
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
echo 'Error';
}

// get values from the form
function getPosts()
{
$posts = array();
$posts[0] = $_POST['personID'];
$posts[1] = $_POST['personFName'];
$posts[2] = $_POST['personLName'];
$posts[3] = $_POST['personAddress'];
$posts[4] = $_POST['personContact'];
$posts[5] = $_POST['personEmail'];
$posts[6] = $_POST['personPassword'];
$posts[7] = $_POST['isVolunteer'];
return $posts;
}

// Search

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
 $data = getPosts();

$search_Query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_people WHERE personID = $data[0]";

$search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);

if($search_Result)
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
        {
            $personID = $row['personID'];
            $personFName = $row['personFName'];
            $personLName = $row['personLName'];
            $personAddress = $row['personAddress'];
            $personContact = $row['personContact'];
            $personEmail = $row['personEmail'];
            $personPassword = $row['personPassword'];
            $isVolunteer = $row['isVolunteer'];
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No Data For This Id';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Result Error';
}
}


// Insert
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
$data = getPosts();
$insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_people`(`personFName`, `personLName`,  `personAddress`,`personContact`,`personEmail`,`personPassword`,`isVolunteer`) 
VALUES  ('$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]')";
try{
    $insert_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_Query);

    if($insert_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
        {
            echo 'Data Inserted';
        }else{
            echo 'Data Not Inserted';
        }
    }
 } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error Insert '.$ex->getMessage();
 }
}

// Delete
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$data = getPosts();
$delete_Query = "DELETE FROM `tbl_people` WHERE `personID` = $data[0]";
try{
    $delete_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $delete_Query);

    if($delete_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
        {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }else{
            echo 'Data Not Deleted';
        }
    }
 } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error Delete '.$ex->getMessage();
 }
}

// Edit
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$data = getPosts();
$update_Query = "UPDATE `tbl_people` SET `personFName`= '$data[1]',`personLName`= '$data[2]',`personAddress`= '$data[3]',
`personContact`= '$data[4]',`personEmail`= '$data[5]',`personPassword`= '$data[6]',`isVolunteer`= '$data[7]'
WHERE `personID` = $data[0]";
try{
    $update_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $update_Query);

    if($update_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
        {
            echo 'Data Updated';
        }else{
            echo 'Data Not Updated';
        }
    }
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
  }
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP INSERT UPDATE DELETE SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="php_insert_update_delete_search.php" method="post">
        Person ID<br><input type="number" name="personID" placeholder="ID" value="<?php echo $personID;?>"><br><br>
        First Name<br><input type="text" name="personFName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $personFName;?>"><br><br>
        Last Name<br><input type="text" name="personLName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $personLName;?>"><br><br>
        Address<br><input type="text" name="personAddress" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $personAddress;?>"><br><br>
        Contact Number<br><input type="mobile" name="personContact" placeholder="Contact" value="<?php echo $personContact;?>"><br><br>
        Email<br><input type="email" name="personEmail" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $personEmail;?>"><br><br>
        Password<br><input type="text" name="personPassword" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo $personPassword;?>"><br><br>
        Active Or Not:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="isVolunteer" value="<?php echo $isVolunteer;?>" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="isVolunteer" value="<?php echo $isVolunteer;?>" />No
        <br><br>
        <div>
            <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">

            <!-- Input For Edit Values -->
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

            <!-- Input For Clear Values -->
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">

            <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
        </div>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You're echoing "person password" on the radio's value? wtf

Comment: if neither radio button gets checked, then `isVolunteer` is NOT submitted with the form - unchecked radios/checkboxes "stay in vegas", so to speak. You're simply ASSUMING all form fields are filled out. You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @PhiterFernandes sorry was a mistake on my behalf.

Comment: you need to set condition for your variable `$isVolunteer` and if matches you need to set attribute `checked="checked"` for your radio button

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main">

<form action="form.php" method="post">
<!---- Radio Button Starts Here ----->
<label class="heading">Radio Buttons :</label>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="Radio 3">Radio 3
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="Radio 4">Radio 4
<?php include'radio_value.php'; ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Get Selected Values">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Link:-https://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/